# Need to call three webflow states in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

We are facing serious performance issues in our application. We need to send three different requests to our backend, when we are using webflow and we are sending them one by one and this is leading to considerable screen loading time.

Can we call three states of webflow in parallel so that we are able to send three requests to our backend in parallel? Or is there any way to load our screen and call one or two methods later?

we need to navigate from retrieveAccInsList view state to  accSummary view state but in between i need to send three different Request to backenf as AccSumary screen contain 3 screen merged,so i need data from three different places.but is the required solution

```
<view-state id="retrieveAccInsList">
    <transition on="openAccount" to="detailForAccountAction">
        <set name="conversationScope.selectedAccount" value="reqSearchHandler.selectedAccIns" />
        <set name="reqSearchHandler.objectToRetrieveCd" value="'RequestSearch'" />
    </transition>
</view-state>

<action-state id="detailForAccountAction">
    <evaluate expression="accountDetail.getDetailsForAccount(ClientDetailRq)"
        result="flowScope.response">
        <attribute name="name" value="detailAccountResponse" />
    </evaluate>
    <transition on="detailAccountResponse.success" to="searchNoteAction" />
    <transition on="detailAccountResponse.error" to="retrieveAccInsList" />
</action-state>

<action-state id="searchNoteAction">
    <evaluate expression="certNotesHandler.searchForNotes()"
        result="flowScope.response">
        <attribute name="name" value="noteResponse" />
    </evaluate>
    <transition on="noteResponse.success" to="searchActivityAction" />
    <transition on="noteResponse.error" to="retrieveAccInsList" />
</action-state>

<action-state id="searchActivityAction">
    <set name="reqSearchHandler.requestStatus" value="'O'" />
    <set name="reqSearchHandler.objectToRetrieveCd" value="'RequestSearch'" />
    <evaluate expression="reqSearchHandler.setparam()" />
    <evaluate expression="reqSearchHandler.searchForRequest(ReqInquireRq)"
        result="flowScope.response">
        <attribute name="name" value="activtiyResponse" />
    </evaluate>
    <transition on="activtiyResponse.success" to="accSummary" />
    <transition on="activtiyResponse.error" to="retrieveAccInsList" />
</action-state
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure; use Ajax. But without further details it's tough to say--why would you need to call three webflow states "in parallel"? It's called "flow" because they're linear (at least within a single conversation; I know you can have multiple flows active at once).

Comment: thanks..i have just put my code and reason above.Please look over it and suggest solution